# Weird bug with emoji : same Id and Name but different skin (and not equal)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, emoji

I work with emoji, and most of the time it's fine. But I have a very nasty bug that I can't fix. My script detects emoji and replaces them. But with very few of them, they seem different when the user uploads the emoji, and when I copy-paste it from my console:

```
Emoji dagger: ️
Emoji dagger too:
```

It's really curious because the first dagger is not equal to the other, so it can't be detected anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Discord emojis are not normal emojis.

Discord Output

```
<(a):emoji_name:7093749473846>
```

Global

If you still don't understant you can try first using a discord emoji copying it and pasting it into a discord channel name. And then with a normal emoji
(`To get a normal emoji make a backslash before a discord emoji and send it, discord will change it into a normal emoji`) to see the difference. This why sometimes you get this problem. It's not a bug but an info not everyone knows

[Before](https://prnt.sc/uglbyo)

[After](https://prnt.sc/uglc8n)

Comment: I use UNICODE emoji only, no custom emoji. The thing is why the dagger is different and not equal to the other ? It seems I have the same problem with ⚔️... Majority of emojis are fine but some of them no...

Comment: Oh, for unicode emojis then yes **most of them are not supported** so that they are tranformed into black'n'white emoji. And i don't think you can do anything about it -v-"